# How to split/divide an array into 2 using php?

Tags: php

Help me to split or divide an array into 2 different arrays. Here is my single array

```
$array = array("1","2","3","4","5","6");
```

I want the above array into two array like below

```
$array1 = array("1","2","3");

$array2 = array("4","5","6");
```

Answer (score 104, accepted):

Use [`array_chunk`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php):

```
$pieces = array_chunk($array, ceil(count($array) / 2));
```

---

If you want them in separate variables (instead of a multi-dimensional array), use [`list`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.list.php):

```
list($array1, $array2) = array_chunk($array, ceil(count($array) / 2));
```

Comment: you have to cast it to int: `$pieces = array_chunk($array, (int) ceil(count($array) / 2));`

Answer (score 32):

[`array_slice`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) works well as long as you know how many elements you want in each array:

```
$array1 = array_slice($array, 0, 3);
$array2 = array_slice($array, 3, 3);
```

Comment: Thanks, more appropriate to me since I needed my array to split at one specific index and not in more than 2 chunks

Comment: Heads up, I used `array_splice` by mistake instead of `array_slice` and got stuck wondering why the original array was changing!