# PHP: How to split array into 2 parts?

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I have an array full of DB records. It could heaps of elements or very little, it changes regularly.

I need to split the array into two equal parts. The reason is I am then passing these arrays to a Laravel view and displaying them into separate columns.

Here is the DB records being pulled:

`$books = Book::where('unitcode', '=', $unitcode['unitcode'])->get();`

If the pull works then I'm running this:

```
return View::make('showbooks')
->with('books', $books);
```

What I want to do is pass `$books1` and `$books2` which is actually `$books` split into 2 parts.

Any ideas on how I could do this? Thanks

Comment: @scrowler Would you please be able to post an answer on its use? I'm quite new to this and am having trouble finding the length of the array to then chunk it.

Comment: `$books = array_chunk($books, count($books)/2);` - split it in half

Comment: @scrowler Thanks! Would getting the other half be as simple as: `$books = array_chunk($books, count($books)/2, count($books);`?

Comment: $books would then contain an array with two keys, each key would contain half of the array. You could also do `list($books1, $books2) = array_chunk($books, count($books)/2);` to get them into variables

Comment: if you use `array_chunk` and it's a odd number of elements, it will create an array with 3 arrays inside of it, not 2 arrays with +1 element in each array.

Comment: @scrowler Wow that's cleaner than I thought it would be. Thank you so much. I couldn't clearly pick that up from the php docs.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy you're right. Best to use `ceil(count($books)/2)` to round up to avoid fractions

Comment: @Ohgodwhy Ok thanks. So I guess I would just check for that 3rd array and print it out in the first column if it exists.

Comment: There won't be a third array. if the array is 14 long, it'll be 7+7, if it's 15 long, it'll be 8+7.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to split/divide an array into 2 using php?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14115976/how-to-split-divide-an-array-into-2-using-php)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This is a one liner:

```
$halved = array_chunk($books, ceil(count($books)/2));
```

Then `$halved[0]` will contain the first half of the array. It will always be 1 element larger in the event that the array contains an odd number of elements. Of course, `$halved[1]` will contain the 2nd half of the array.

[Here's a working example](https://eval.in/184321)

Answer (score 1):

I think this will work for you.

```
<?php
    $books = array("a", "b", "c", "d", "e","f"); // assuming books is an array like this
    $count = count($books); // total count of the array books
    $half = $count/2; // half of the total count
    $books1 = array_slice($books, 0, $half);      // returns first half
    $books2 = array_slice($books, $half);  // returns second half

    print_r($books1);
    print_r($books2);
?>
```

Comment: If `$books` has an odd number of elements, one element will be left off... I would remove the 2nd `$half` parameter for `$books2`, that way you get the rest of the array from where `$books1` ended...

Answer (score 0):

I think you should take the length of the array using the count method and then loop the items till the middle it should look like this :

```
<?php 
    $count = count($books);            //getting the count of $books
    $mid = round($count/2);           //getting the mid point of $books
    for($i = 0; $i < $count ; $i++){ //looping through the indexes
        if($i <= mid - 1){          //Checking the position of $i and adding the value
            $books1[] = $books[$i];
        }else{
            $books2[] = $books[$i];
        }
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

To expand on [Ohgodwhy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1206267/ohgodwhy)'s answer:

Since you're using [laravel](/questions/tagged/laravel), here's a more fluent way to achieve this:

```
$books = collect($books);

$halved = $books->split(ceil($books->count()/2))->toArray();

// Result: [[a, b, c], [d, e, f]]
```

Take a look at Laravel's various [Collection Methods](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections#available-methods) for more available methods to fluently manipulate arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
$collection->chunk(2);
```

See:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections#method-chunk

Answer (score 0):

## splitIn()

The splitIn method breaks a collection into the given number of groups, filling non-terminal groups completely before allocating the remainder to the final group:

```
$collection = collect([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]);
 
$groups = $collection->splitIn(3);
 
$groups->all();

// [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10]]
```