# Split array to equal sized array

Tags: php, laravel

I need to split array for 4 arrays next way. How can I do it more elegant? Each element goes to subarray while parent array not empty.

```
$mainblocks = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12];
$sliders = [];

$slider_index = 0;
foreach ($mainblocks as $mainblock) {
    $sliders[$slider_index][] = $mainblock;
    if ($slider_index >= 3) {
        $slider_index = 0;
        continue;
    }
    $slider_index++;
}

print_r($sliders);
```

The expected output is: [[1,5,9] [2,6,10] [3,7,11] [4,8,12]]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to split/divide an array into 2 using php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14115976/how-to-split-divide-an-array-into-2-using-php)

Comment: @Patrick Q I don't think it is a duplicate. Pay attention at the example code given, it sort of zig-zags in the original array, its output would be [1,5,9] [2,6,10] [3,7,11] [4,8,12], not what the question you pointed out is about.

Comment: @YuriNudelman If OP has requirements beyond "I need to split array for 4 arrays", it needs to be explicit in the question.

Comment: @Patrick Q Question requires editing to make it more clear I agree, but supplied piece of code behavior is well defined.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at `array_chunk()`:

```
$input_array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12];
print_r(array_chunk($input_array, 3)); // output: [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9],[10,11,12]]
```

**Description:**

```
array_chunk ( array $array , int $size [, bool $preserve_keys = FALSE ] ) : array
```

> Chunks an array into arrays with size elements. The last chunk may contain less than size elements.

**Edit:**

For your requirements:

```
$mainblocks = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12];
for($i = 0; $i <= sizeof($mainblocks) / 4; $i++)
    for($j = 1; $j <= sizeof($mainblocks); $j = $j + 4)
        $sliders[$i][] = $mainblocks[$j - 1 + $i];
print_r($sliders); // output: [[1,5,9] [2,6,10] [3,7,11] [4,8,12]]
```

Comment: no, I need chunck all data from first array only to 4 subarrayes. array_chunk() - chunck all data from first array to many subarrayes with $size values.

Comment: @Teretto So you just divide the length of the array by 4, and use that as your chunk size.

Comment: @Teretto I think I misunderstood your question at first. I have edited my answer according to your needs.

Answer (score 2):

You want to **chunk** and **transpose**.

Here is a one-liner using array_map() and the splat operator (`...`) to unpack the chunks. Notice that if the chunks aren't even, you get NULL placeholding elements.

If you don't want NULL placeholders, you'll need to use foreach loops instead of array_map.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/HJMEMv))

```
$mainblocks = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12];

var_export(array_map(null, ...array_chunk($mainblocks, 4)));

echo "\n---\n";

$mainblocks = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];

var_export(array_map(null, ...array_chunk($mainblocks, 4)));
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    0 => 1,
    1 => 5,
    2 => 9,
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    0 => 2,
    1 => 6,
    2 => 10,
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    0 => 3,
    1 => 7,
    2 => 11,
  ),
  3 => 
  array (
    0 => 4,
    1 => 8,
    2 => 12,
  ),
)
---
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    0 => 1,
    1 => 5,
    2 => 9,
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    0 => 2,
    1 => 6,
    2 => 10,
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    0 => 3,
    1 => 7,
    2 => NULL,
  ),
  3 => 
  array (
    0 => 4,
    1 => 8,
    2 => NULL,
  ),
)
```

Comment: @Teretto Does this work as desired for your actual project data?